# TextMate: Highlight matching tags of caret location

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting, textmate

Is it possible for TextMate to syntax highlight the opening and closing tags of your current caret location? And I am talking about constantly, not by pressing a key combo.

Furthermore, if it possible, how can I do it? There doesn't seem to be any way that I know of except by using selectors in the theme, but I don't know if selectors can be context-sensitive.

Comment: I looked for a way to do this in the past but didn't come up with anything. I'm hoping someone out there smarter than me has a solution.

Comment: Do you mean just the lowest level in the DOM? As you are always inside html, and usually head/body too.

Comment: After a bit of research, it seems unlikely this is possible at this stage. TM2 may be different, but my approach was looking at scope. You may be able to have a different html bundle that handles scopes differently, but even then it looks challenging.

Comment: Thanks... it's just one of those things that helps when coding a lot by hand. Hopefully in a future release it'll be a possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently, the TextMate language grammar has no concept of cursor position. Therefore, this is not achievable right now.

A workaround that I use is to define macros that select a block of text whose boundaries I define with regular expressions. You have to be handy with regular expressions, but you can make it work.

Essentially, record a new macro (option-command-m), use the find dialog to search for the beginning of the tag. Then, use the find dialog and provide a reg-ex that will match the entire contents you want to select. Press option-command-m again to stop the macro, and then save the macro to a bundle.

An example here:

http://github.com/timcharper/vines.tmbundle/blob/master/Macros/Select%20Tag.tmMacro

Tim

Comment: Thanks for the information. I wonder if you could have this macro execute every time you move the caret in the editor but I would assume this would slow things down.